# Ways to identify duplicate and mistagged questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I've been hanging around [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) on Stack Overflow recently. One thing I am noticing is that people often tag their question as [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) when it regards [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).

Now according to the [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) wiki, you should not tag your question as [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) if it specifically about [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails). It seems like a problems that is quite common among tags that people are duplicating and mistagging their questions.

I had a question today where the person asked about [git](/questions/tagged/git) but tagged it as [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby).

Perhaps there should be a notice or warning (much like the "Questions that may already have your answer" dropdown) when people place similar tags together (i.e. [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)).

Thoughts?

Comment: Seems a bit localized to a handful of specific tags, and would be very hard to write an effective implementation of.

Comment: How about processing tags for subsets of the name. Such that you would get a warning when you tagged [Ruby] and [Ruby-on-Rails] since Ruby is a subset of Ruby on Rails. You would also get a warning when you tagged [Ruby-on-Rails] and [Ruby-on-Rails-4] for the same reason.

Comment: in many cases you don't *want* questions tags with a language specific version instead of the general version.  People subscribe to the general version rather than the language specific version in many cases, so they wouldn't see such questions.

Comment: I wonder how many people tagged their questions with ruby on rails when in fact the problem was with them not knowing something about Ruby itself. We certainly have it that way with JavaScript and jQuery.